Jupyter is not installing through cmd
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
  Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

  Checking for Rust toolchain....
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
After installing rust, it is throwing this error...
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywinpty
Failed to build pywinpty
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pywinpty)

This question is similar to: Error installing Jupyter & pywinpty (Python). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am able to install jupyterlab and jupyter successfully on python 3.13 successfully.

Same thing happened for bunch of libraries during the release of 3.12, mainly because developers take time to update the source code for 3.13 compatibility. So, it will also be updated in couple of days or weeks possibly.

Python 3.13 is recently released. It is possible that jupyter(or it's dependency packages) might not support Python 3.13 yet. Try downgrading your python version to 3.12.
See also: python-3-13-failed-to-install-jupyter
